# Choosing which font for html export syntax highlighting?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Exporting org mode documents to html with `(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)` will carry syntax highlighting into the exported code blocks.

Zenburn looks awful exported while Leuven/others looks fantastic. I do all my work in Zenburn.

Can html-export use a specified font for source code highlighting? Running (in spacemacs) the command `Space T n` changes the font, but it is not practical to keep going back and forth whenever I wish to html-export.

The following article http://emacs-fu.blogspot.com/2010/05/using-zenburn-for-org-mode-generated.html I found during my search but the provided solution is neither the same nor works.